# .NET Core MS Bot - MS Teams. OAuthPrompt on mobile side (android) doesn't show login page (authorize)

Tags: android, botframework, microsoft-teams

Topic: .NET Core 3.1, MS Bot - MS Teams.

I use "OAuth Connection Settings" to authorize in my system + OAuthPrompt dialog. Works fine.
But I can't login to my system from mobile teams application (Android). I press the button but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add to manifest.json this

```
"devicePermissions": [
    "openExternal"
  ]
```

Work for me.